# Unable to performSegue successfully after Callback

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm trying to make a SignUp button with action, when button tapped a function called getVPhoneNumber is started. and it initiate a phone verification API called `Digits by Fabric` with a popover VC after the phone verification is successful the completion should contain the phone number as String, and the `result var` in SignUp btn should receive that number so it can performSeague to another VC.

**The problem is it doesn't the performSegue, just stays at**

Login View Controller:

```
    func getVPhoneNumber(completion: @escaping (_ result: String)->()) {

        let configuration = DGTAuthenticationConfiguration(accountFields: .defaultOptionMask)

        configuration?.appearance = DGTAppearance()
        configuration?.appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        configuration?.appearance.accentColor = UIColor.red

        // Start the Digits authentication flow with the custom appearance.
        Digits.sharedInstance().authenticate(with: nil, configuration:configuration!) { (session, error) in
            if session != nil {

                //Print Data
                print(session?.phoneNumber!)
                print(session?.userID!)

                //Assign Value to global var vPhoneNumber.
                self.vPhoneNumber = session?.phoneNumber!

                print("TESTING COMPLETION")
                completion((session?.phoneNumber!)!)

            } else {
                print("Error")
            }

        }

    }

//SignUp Button: 

     @IBAction func signUpPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        getVPhoneNumber() { (result) -> () in
            // do stuff with the result
            print(result)

            print("Going To SignUp VC")
            self.navigateToMainAppScreen()

        }
    }

//NavigateToMainApScreen Function

    fileprivate func navigateToMainAppScreen() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSignUpVC", sender: nil)
    }
```

Storyboard overview:

[image: storyboard]

NOTE: the "Going To SignUp VC" is not printed in the console until the phone verification process is completed and thats what I want, but since it continued the process by printing that statement why didn't it initiate the PerformSegue ? Why only printed the statement.

Thanks in advance and I'm sorry if some of my explanation was not clear.

Comment: So the only problem is that the segue isn't executed? Everything else works as expected? Can we see your `navigateToMainAppScreen` function? :)

Comment: yes only the seague isn't executed and everything else works as expected, I'm going to add 'navigateToMainAppScreen' code now :)

Comment: Are you calling `performSegue` on main thread?

Comment: @ReeceKenney check my update :)

Comment: Shouldn't sender be `self`?

Comment: Sender can be anything you want, including `nil`.  The perform needs to be dispatched on the main queue

Comment: Ah okay, thanks @Paulw11

Comment: your code is fine and correct , only one mistake just chnage the segue type

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik my current segue type is Show (Between Login VC and the Navigation Controller as in the screenshot) , to which type should I change it to work ?

Comment: @HusseinAlBehary - check the updated answer

Comment: How is your segue invoked? Your code does not show it. Is the segue attached to the login button? If so, it should not be. You should attach the segue to the scene and then invoke it (from the main thread) in your completion handler.

Comment: @DuncanC Hey Dunac, my Segue is already attached to the scene not the buttons :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fileprivate func navigateToMainAppScreen() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSignUpVC", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

EDIT:
The error from the comment `"2017-04-23 12:31:39.127 b-Donor[6365:130139] Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x7fc2fb878600> on <DGTNavigationViewController: 0x7fc2fa85a600> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!` suggests your custom `DGTNavigationViewController` is not being used properly in place of `UINavigationController`, please check if in Navigation Controller storyboard you set the custom `DGTNavigationViewController` class properly (in the right most XCode pane).

Comment: Ok when I updated my code for yours, I got that on my console: `"2017-04-23 12:31:39.127 b-Donor[6365:130139] Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x7fc2fb878600> on <DGTNavigationViewController: 0x7fc2fa85a600> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!` and didn't perform the seague

Comment: You need to give some context how methods you quote relate to your view controllers (aka in which classes those methods are defined)